# Problem with Python dictionaries using dict() function

Tags: python, dictionary

Why do these two seemingly identical dictionaries behave differently?

```
normal_dict = {1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0]}
print(f'Original normal_dict = {normal_dict}')

problem_dict = dict(zip([1,2], len([1,2])*[[0,0]]))      
print(f'Original problem_dict = {problem_dict}')

normal_dict[1][1] += 100
print(f'Amended normal_dict = {normal_dict}')

problem_dict[1][1] += 100
print(f'Amended problem_dict = {problem_dict}')
```

Output:

```
Original normal_dict = {1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0]}
Original problem_dict = {1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0]}
Amended normal_dict = {1: [0, 100], 2: [0, 0]}
Amended problem_dict = {1: [0, 100], 2: [0, 100]}
```

Comment: Because `2 * [[0,0]]` makes two references to *the same list*.  Use `[[0,0] for _ in range(2)]` instead.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you elaborate on how the two references arise?

Comment: OK Mark, I get your point now, thank you.